# Deleted dimension still show up in aggregation process

Tags: experience-analytics

I have a particular issue with `Sitecore 9.0.1`. I need to create a custom flexible dimension. Initially I create the dimension and register it in the configuration file. Subsequently I deleted it from both master & web databases (and from the configuration file). 
However the aggregation process still show this error:

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Dimension could
>   not be resolved for for dimension id:
>   c22ee43a-b981-4a20-8de0-63a4877a02b1 Source:
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation    at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Data.Model.AggregationSegment.get_Dimension()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Data.Model.AggregationSegment.GetData(IVisitAggregationContext
>   context)    at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.SegmentProcessor.ProcessSegments(IInteractionAggregationContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 segments)

The dimension id above is the one that I created and deleted. 
Please tell me what else do I need to do. Or is this a bug in Sitecore 9.0.1?

Regards,
Hiep